# CreateProcessA: What to do with hProcess for background process?

Tags: windows

Visual Studio /analyze build warns me that I'm leaking `PROCESS_INFORMATION.hProcess` after starting a background process with `CreateProcessA`.  I don't need to wait for that process, and it will exit on its own when it is time.  **Is there something I should do with `hProcess` in that case?**

This is /analyze result [C6335](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f81c0859-3d82-4182-8bf1-6c3b76c7486f%28VS.110%29.aspx)

Comment: `CloseHandle(hProcess);` to tell the operating system you are finished with it.

Comment: Make sure to also `CloseHandle(hThread);` while at it. Both handles need to be closed even if you are not waiting for the process to end. From [CreateProcess function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms682425.aspx): `Handles in PROCESS_INFORMATION must be closed with CloseHandle when they are no longer needed.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is call CloseHandle once you no longer care about it, which, in your case, sounds like right after you create the process.

You might be worried that this would prematurely terminate the process, but it won't.  The process also holds a handle to itself.  The OS won't destroy the process object until the last handle to it is closed.